# Join does not work on two identical fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to join two tables on sql server 2008.

```
select *
from TABLE1 a
left join TABLE2 b
on a.cont_id = b.cont_id
```

However, it is not able to connect any of the data.

**a.cont_id** is of *nvarchar*(255) type and **b.cont_id** is *varchar*(80). Using CAST in any way didn't help.

As **a.cont_id** consists of only numerical data, at first I used type float and integer and applied cast function, but that didn't solve anything.

I checked their varbinary codes by using the following query

```
select cont_id, CAST(cont_id AS varbinary) AS BinaryCode
from Table1 
where cont_id = '53126124'

select cont_id, CAST(cont_id AS varbinary) AS BinaryCode
from Table2
where cont_id = '53126124'
```

and I got these two results

```
cont_id     BinaryCode
53126124    0x4189551F60000000


cont_id     BinaryCode
53126124    0x3533313236313234
```

One more information - Table 1 is imported from the excel document that was created in neighbour country (Czech republic).

As for the source tables, here is an example, if it helps.

```
 cont_id    C1      C2   C3
 53126124   3       31   510
175553321   5       16       510
```

And

```
dt      cont_id   D1  D2
201610  53126124  0   0 
201610  175553321 41  520
```

Do you have any idea how to deal with this?

Comment: How do they look in their normal format ?

Comment: Why is numerical data being stored as varchars and nVarchars?

Comment: Perhaps you have spaces? `on trim(a.con_id) = trim(b.con_id)`  if not then perhaps other non-display characters you could try to do a len on both for the same ID and see if len returns the same value, my guess is not.

Comment: and 2. what do you get from `Select cast(con_id as numeric) from table_1`  `Select cast(con_id as numeric) from table_2` ?

Comment: How did you check the 'varbinary codes?' The difference between `VARCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` shouldn't be more than double zeros after each two characters. Try this `SELECT CAST(N'53126124' AS VARBINARY(MAX)),CAST('53126124' AS VARBINARY(MAX))`

Comment: Hi, if I cast them as numeric, I get in both cases the same - 53126124.

Comment: Please show code! What are you casting. Don't think, that the above is casteable to numeric...

Comment: Only in one table the variable is numerical, in another one it may also contain letters. But as I said, at first I imported the data as float or integer and applied cast. Nothing worked for me.

Comment: select cont_id, CAST(cont_id AS numeric) AS cont_num
    from table1 
    where cont_id = '53126124'

Comment: Once again: How did you do this *I checked their varbinary codes*? This is - quite probably - a data type issue and you do not provide the right information...

Comment: And checking the varbinary code:

select cont_id, CAST(cont_id AS varbinary) AS BinaryCode
from table1
where cont_id = '53126124'

Comment: Please show some code and provide a couple of rows of sample data from each table.

Comment: And the other value? You found a difference... The one with `0x41...` Where does it come from?

Comment: Can you provide an example: Write some code, create a minimal table, insert values, try to melt this down to a minimal, complete, verifiable example (MCVE).

Comment: I am going to update the question with the code you ask.

Comment: Just to get this sure: In some places you are speaking about `cont_id`, on other places it's `con_id`. One column and a typo, or two columns? Are you sure about the data types `nvarchar(255)` and `varchar(80)`? Might there be any steps involved (views, functions ...) which could change this type?

Comment: Hi, I am sorry. It is always cont_id (I overwrote the code several times). And yes, I checked the types once again and they are the same. But I imported the table 1 with the cont_id of float type as well, and the binary code was still this strange 0x4189551F60000000.

Comment: Copy-paste from Excel into character fields may add CR+LF at the end of field value - quite nasty to find out. Replace char(13) and char(10) with empty strings - does something improve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I've got it:

This

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(53126124 AS FLOAT) AS VARBINARY)
```

results in `0x4189551F60000000`, while this

```
SELECT CAST('53126124' AS varbinary)
```

results in `0x3533313236313234`, while this

```
SELECT CAST(53126124 AS varbinary)
```

comes back with `0x032AA3EC`.

The first value is the varbinary representation of a `FLOAT`, the second of a `VARCHAR` and the last of an `INT`.

**Obviously the first IS NOT `VARCHAR`!**

Float types tend to be unprecise, there might be a tiny value like `1,0000000001` or `0.999999998` which is considered as `1`, but is not equal.

You might try with this:

```
select *
from TABLE1 a
left join TABLE2 b
on CAST(ROUND(a.cont_id,0) AS INT) = CAST(ROUND(b.cont_id,0) AS INT)
```

Comment: Thank you. This finally gives me the same binary code for both of them. As for the type problem - I checked the type using this query
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table1'
and it really is varchar. But it is probably another topic and not important now as you managed to solve it anyway.